# How to get rid of the cick delay. It takes like 2 seconds in Ipad

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

This is my sample code, It takes like 2 seconds for the changes to happen

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let week of month.fullweeks; let weekindex =index" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                      <ion-col *ngFor="let day of week;let i = index" tappable (click)="selectday(day,monthindex,i,weekindex)" >
                        <div class="day"  [ngClass]="{'startactive':(day.style == 1),'finishactive':(day.style == 2)}" ><div *ngIf="day.day != 0" >{{day.day}}</div></div>
                      </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
```

Comment: Have you tried by using `(tap)="..."` instead of `(click)="..."`?

Comment: Tap doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by updating Ionic Scripts and not using inline css